# Pygame.mixer won't initialize channels (mono vs stereo)

Tags: python, pygame, mono, mixer

I'm trying to play mono sounds on two channels using pygame.mixer.

However, setting channels = 1 doesn't do the trick for me. It seems that it doesn't take the value I give to the init functions.

I tried several combinations:

```
import pygame as pg

def setupAudio(self):
    print("Test")
    pg.mixer.quit()
    pg.mixer.init(self.fs, -16,1)
    print(pg.mixer.get_init())
```

```
import pygame as pg

def setupAudio(self):
    print("Test")
    pg.mixer.quit()
    pg.mixer.pre_init(frequency = self.fs, channels = 1)
    pg.mixer.init(self.fs, -16,1)
    print(pg.mixer.get_init())
```

```
import pygame as pg

def setupAudio(self):
    print("Test")
    pg.mixer.quit()
    pg.mixer.pre_init(frequency = self.fs, channels = 1)
    pg.mixer.init(self.fs, -16,1)
    pg.init()
    print(pg.mixer.get_init())
```

For all results I get printed:

Test
(44100,-16,2)

I even tried putting in channels = 4, which gave me no error/throwback (which I would assume, as this is not a valid input).

Can someone help me out, am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation apparently does not support `channels=1` (or `channels=4`), so it changes to match what the implementation can directly handle.

To force the parameters you want and make someone else in the background make the conversion for you you can set [`allowedchanges=0`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init):

`pg.mixer.pre_init(frequency = self.fs, channels = 1, allowedchanges=0)`

Or if you want to keep that auto change of `frequency`, you can instead use `allowedchanges=pg.AUDIO_ALLOW_FREQUENCY_CHANGE`